# Android Studios . Cargar Spinner con todos los nombre de las canciones que tenga en el directorio raw

Tags: java, android, programación-móvil

esoty haciendo una especie de lista de reproduccion. Estoy trabajando con el directorio "raw" de android studios donde se meten videos... musica etc.. y lo que pretendo es que, en una de las ventanas (activitys) de esta se encarge de dar de alta una cancion para que acabe en la lista, mi intencion es que en el spinner de la izquierda salga el nombre de las canciones que recorra de la carpeta raw y los cargue, y no estoy consiguiendo hacerlo
 [image: El espiner que pone **-Elige una Musica-** debe cargar todos los archivos mp3 de la carpeta raw]

he conseguido hacer una chapucilla, pero para uno solo en concreto, ahora me quedaria recorrer la carpeta raw para cargar todos los raw que tenga en vez de especificarlo yo

aqui el ejemplo

public void cargarSpinnerMusica() {
        ArrayList nombreMusicas = new ArrayList<>();
        nombreMusicas.add("-- Elige una Musica --");
        try {

```
        String lector = getResources().getResourceName(R.raw.atiquetesalelodellocahostnoelerrorese);
        String nombre_real = lector.split("/")[1];

        nombreMusicas.add(nombre_real);

      //  lector.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, nombreMusicas);
    spinner_musicas.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Has intentado buscando los nombres de los archivos que contiene el directorio raw?

Comment: mi problema con eso es que no se la ruta relativa de eso entonces en cuanto lo aplique al movil deja de funcionar

Comment: Dar de alta una canción y se agregué a la lista dentro de /raw ??? **recuerda que raw es de solo lectura**, por lo tanto esto no se podría realizar.